# Generated columns using aggregate functions

Tags: mysql

### The starting point

Suppose I have a table `devTest` that looks like this:

```
+----+------+  
| id | j    |  
+----+------+  
|  1 |    5 |  
|  2 |    9 |  
|  3 |    4 |  
|  4 |    7 |  
+----+------+
```

### The goal

I want a column specifying the row's deviation from the mean in the j column (expressed in standard deviations). That is, the table would look like this:

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | j    | jDev       |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 |    5 | -0.5637345 |
|  2 |    9 | 1.2402159  |
|  3 |    4 | -1.0147221 |
|  4 |    7 | 0.3382407  |
+----+------+------------+
```

### What I've tried

```
>alter table devTest add column jDev decimal as ((j - avg(j)) / std(j));
```

To which I receive an error indicating that aggregate functions can't be used in the definition of a generated column:

```
ERROR 1901 (HY000): Function or expression 'avg()' cannot be used in the 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `jDev`
```

Making this kind of column must be pretty common, so I'd love to know the best solution!

Comment: Side note: isn't [STD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_std) already the standard deviation of your population ? No need to divide by average ?

Comment: Why a static column? Maintaining it will be a pita (but possible with triggers, albeit somewhat innefficient depending on the read/write ratio)

Comment: @BenjaminCrouzier I haven't divided by the average; I've taken the difference between each row and the column average and expressed that difference in units of standard deviations. Thanks for suggesting  views; along with Thorsten's expression, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard SQL you'd do:

```
select id, j, (j - avg(j) over ()) / std(j) over () as jdev
from devtest;
```

But MySQL doesn't support analytic window functions such as `AVG OVER`. So in MySQL, you must select the aggregation values separately:

```
select d.id, d.j, (d.j - agg.javg) / agg.jstd as jdev
from devtest d
cross join (select avg(j) as javg, std(j) as jstd from devtest) agg;
```

Then create a view as Benjamin Crouzier suggests in his answer:

```
CREATE VIEW v_devtest AS
  select d.id, d.j, (d.j - agg.javg) / agg.jstd as jdev
  from devtest d
  cross join (select avg(j) as javg, std(j) as jstd from devtest) agg;
```

A computed column can only calculate its value from other values in the same record. So what you are trying to do cannot be done with a calculated column.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten; that'll do nicely! Having a little (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291779/mysql-view-definer-permissions-and-error-1356) trouble accessing this view, but permission wonkery aside, I've verified this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This error makes sense because any change in your table (say you add a `j` with value 0) would update your average, and this in turn would change all your generated columns. So this would be quite a bit of work for the query engine.

Another solution would be to define a view instead:

```
CREATE VIEW j_dev (id, j, j_dev) AS 
SELECT id, j, 
       (j - avg(j)) / std(j) as j_dev
FROM devTest
```

(not sure about the create view syntax, correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: You are right to suggest a view. The query however cannot work. When you use aggregate functions such as `AVG` without a `GROUP BY` you only get one result row. You need a query that includes both a selectton of the single records and a selection of the aggregation values.