# Creating MySql View with Laravel -> Query works. Migration moves it to MySql where it fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So i'm trying to use a MySQL view in Lavavel 8.

The SQL works fine and creates a list of dates into the future (and the past) that i later plan to join Bookings or Calender blocks too.

However, when Laravel Migrates the query to MYSQL, its doesn't work and throws this error..

***Error Code: 1356. View 'ccc.calender_days' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them    0.000 sec***

The working MySQL Query in the Migration is here:

```
private function createView(): string
    {
        return <<<SQL
            CREATE VIEW `calender_days` AS

            select * from 
                (select adddate('2000-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) date from
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
            where date between CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 DAY and CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 5 DAY 
        SQL;
    }
```

This is the resulting MySQL code

```
 CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `ccc`.`calender_days` AS
    SELECT 
        `v`.`date` AS `date`
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            '2000-01-01' + INTERVAL `t4`.`i` * 10000 + `t3`.`i` * 1000 + `t2`.`i` * 100 + `t1`.`i` * 10 + `t0`.`i` DAY AS `date`
        FROM
            (((((SELECT 0 AS `i` UNION SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t0`
        JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `i` UNION SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t1`)
        JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `i` UNION SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t2`)
        JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `i` UNION SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t3`)
        JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `i` UNION SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t4`)) `v`
    WHERE
        `v`.`date` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

I think the issues is with the opening "Definer" statements but not sure where to look!?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As i was going through may be you could also check this one may be it could help resolving the case.

Reference link: [MySQL view definer permissions and error 1356](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291779/mysql-view-definer-permissions-and-error-1356)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ntonsite mwamlima. That helped. But only if edited the mysql side of things.
But needed to be able to define the View through Laravel, which I wasn't able to do with the change to "Invoker".

In the end, the fix was pretty simple. I needed to add the following Definer line to my Migration file...

```
private function createView(): string
{
    return <<<SQL
        CREATE 
        DEFINER = `root`@`localhost`    
        VIEW `calender_days` AS

        select * from
```