# Newbie on SQL -- having trouble using Window Functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table in mysql which has a column called CAGR (type: DECIMAL).

My intent is to generate always a new column that computes the average of CAGR on each row (will be the same all the way down).  I can't seem to figure it out.

First I test that I can do it with a SELECT Statement -- I can -- Here is the statement I used:

```sql
SELECT Name,
       AVG(CAGR) OVER () "avg_cagr"
FROM Table;
```

I ran the above, and it works.  I get the header (Name and avg_cagr) and the Name and the same avg_cagr for each of my rows.  Great.

Next, I'm ready to create my new column using GENERTAED AS.  Here's what I wrote:

```
ALTER TABLE Table
ADD COLUMN CAGR_AVG DECIMAL(12,2)
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (AVG (CAGR) OVER ()) STORED NULL;
```

This does not work. I get the following response:

> Error Code: 3593. You cannot use the window function 'avg' in this context.'

Why?

Comment: A generated column can only see the current row - you need to create a *view*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generated columns using aggregate functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266166/generated-columns-using-aggregate-functions)

Comment: How would I modify my statement to create view?

Comment: why do you want to do this?  if you need the average of all rows, just include that in your select just like you are doing.  a view isn't going to make this any more efficient, it's just going to hide what's happening better

Comment: Thank you!  But I thought I was using the window function average (as in the first statement I wrote with the select command) and not the aggregate function. As for creating a view to solve the problem, How would I modify my alter table generate statement to create a view?

Comment: I want my table to have this pre calculated in every row for easy retrieval by another API. I intend to have a column each for the average , the median (each of which will be the same for each row) and then a percentile_rank which will be different for each row

Comment: 'I want my table to have this pre calculated in every row for easy retrieval by another API.'  Why not make the view available to the api rather than the table?

Answer (score 1):

In a virtual column you cannot use information from other rows. One solution is to use a VIEW.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE myTable(
> CAGR DECIMAL(5,2),
> Name VARCHAR(10));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO myTable VALUES
> (2.5,'one'),
> (7.9,'two'),
> (15,'three');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW myView AS
> SELECT 
>   Name, 
>   CAGR,
>   AVG (CAGR) OVER () "avg_cagr" 
> FROM myTable;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM myView;
> ```
>
> ```
> Name  |  CAGR | avg_cagr
> :---- | ----: | -------:
> one   |  2.50 | 8.466667
> two   |  7.90 | 8.466667
> three | 15.00 | 8.466667
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=40ffef7e239c26722f5b9866ee75a9ee)*